# Jenkins build fails intermittnetly due to SVN timeout

Tags: svn, jenkins

We are using Jenkins for CI on .NET projects.  SVN is our repository.  Our projects build perfectly fine 99% of the time, but every other day or so we get a failure.

It seems to be due to SVN timing out.  here's part of the stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage: svn: timed out waiting for server
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:200)
```

But one minute later the next attempt at building the exact same project works perfectly fine.

Is there a way to tell Jenkins to "try again"?  I would prefer to only ever receive notifications for true errors, not these intermittent things, as that dilutes the value of the alters.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to set the 'SCM checkout retry count' to the number of SVN operation retry attempts. It could be found in 'Advanced Project Options' section of your job configuration page when you check the 'Retry Count' option.

Comment: Thanks.  I have set this, and will let it run another day and see if this fixes the issue, then award points.

Comment: Nope, set retry to 3, and still get fails about once a day.  I don't see that setting this made a difference.

Comment: @DanielWilliams. You mean jenkins did not retry or it failed even after multiple retries?

Comment: What the job's log says - do you see the lines like 'Retrying after 10 seconds' or similar ?  What error (or exception) is reported: is it like SVNException or ChannelClosedException or some other ?  What version of Jenkins and Subversion Plugin is used ?